# how to compare real/float while using "AND" .(unix)

Tags: unix

I'm new to shell scripting, I have written a small script to check if the input is in the specified (integer) range:

```
echo "Enter number btw 50 and 100:"

read num

if [ $num -le 100 -a $num -ge 50 ];
then 
    echo "you are in limits."
else 
    echo "you are out of limits."
fi
```

How can I check if a number is in a real/floating range?

Answer (score 0):

You can't with sh/<strike>ksh</strike><sup>1</sup>/bash(/zsh?) -- integer arithmetic only.

You can do something like

```
if [ "$(echo "50 <= $num && $num <= 100" | bc)" = "1" ]; then
    echo "you are in limits."
else
    echo "you are out of limits."
fi
```

(<sup>1</sup> - ksh93 can do floating point arithmetic)